# gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "DeviceType=3"...Why invalid query?

Tags: powershell

Excused me for a newbie to ask a newbie's question:)
simple code:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "DeviceType=3"
```

Why invalid query? I think it's because I'm not famaliar with this -filter, is there any good pages about this -filter that I can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not DeviceType but DriveType (or possibly DeviceID). You can look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173.aspx) to see what properties are available, or simply pipe to get-member:

```
PS C:\> $drive = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk
PS C:\> $drive | get-member
...
```

Bill